# Conditional formatting not working on range

Tags: excel

I have a 5 column 5 row range H2:M6. I have a date in column M. If M = a date in $C$40 I want that whole row highlighted. It works perfectly for the M column. Columns are formatted as Text, Currency, Currency, Date, Date. I can conditionally format each column separately but I have 10 columns x 12 sheets to add conditional formatting to. I have made sure that the following formula works on each column:
My formula is =IF($C$40<>"",M2=$C$40,).
Funny though, if I apply the rule to only L2:M6 it only highlights column L, not column M also. Column L and M are 90% always the same date but do vary.
Is it something to do with the formula using dates and the rest of the columns aren't dates? But that wouldn't explain it not formatting column M in the last example.
David

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Formatting makes no difference.  Probably you've applied the conditional formatting incorrectly.  Edit your post in accordance with the guidance of @YagamiLight, and also see  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can reproduce your problem and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
=AND(COUNTA($C$40)=1,$M2=$C$40)
```

- CountA($C$40)=1 will make sure $C$40<>"" (Date of 0 is converted to 01-01-1900 in Excel)
- $M2 will make sure it is always column M even if you select multiple column
- And() is the combination of the True result for both conditions

You can select all Columns and use Conditional Formatting using the above formula.

Comment: Thanks Yass, all works perfectly,  if I had a $ for every time I left a $ out.....